# How to enable the icons of the picked up items on screen in C# and Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wrote code in order to pick-up items after pressing the button "E" and then print the icon of the picked-up item on the screen, but the code did not work correctly because when the button is pressed, all of the icons are activated at the same time, as shown in the screenshot below.
I expected when I pick up an item its icon will active on the screen.

Any suggestions please to solve this problem?

[image]

The code is below:

```
public GameObject screwDriverWithPlayer, cutterWithPlayer,PicUpText;
public RawImage screwDriver, cutter;
private bool active;

void Start()
{
    screwDriverWithPlayer.SetActive(false);
    cutterWithPlayer.SetActive(false);
    PicUpText.SetActive(false);
    screwDriver.enabled = false;
    cutter.enabled = false;
}

private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        PicUpText.SetActive(true);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            screwDriverWithPlayer.SetActive(true);
            screwDriver.enabled = true;
           
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            cutterWithPlayer.SetActive(true);
            cutter.enabled = true;
            PicUpText.SetActive(false);
        }
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    PicUpText.SetActive(false);       
}
```

Comment: Because when you press E, both get enabled? What are you expecting exactly?

Comment: I expect when I pick-up item its icon will active on the screen

Comment: And where is the logic between choosing which one gets enabled? I don't see it here.

Comment: So that I am here because I do not know how to solve this problem

Comment: There seems to be no distinguishing in this script on whether it's attached to a cutter or screwdriver. I would start from there, and then add logic to enable either image depending on what it's attached to.

Comment: Thanks, bro, I hope you find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem is a correct understanding of the principles of **object-oriented** programming. So, in the first step, create a script named **Item** and drop it on the objects that have **isTrigger** Colliders. You can create a method to pick them up as below or any other parameter you want.

```cs
public class Item : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image UI_Image;
    public void PickUp()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
        UI_Image.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        //....
    }
}
```

Since you have a player and dozens of items, you should not install the `OnTriggerStay` code on the items, which will put additional performance on the computer. A better solution is to put `OnTriggerStay` on the player and execute each item from its component as below.

```cs
// IN THE PLAYER SCRIPT!!
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)) // First Check KEY cuz of optimization
    {
        if(other.gameObject.TryGetComponent(out Item item))
        {
            item.PickUp();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to include the `UI_Image` of each item as well. This method is sufficient for unique items, but if you want to create a professional inventory system, you will definitely need to work with **List** and **Scriptable object**.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. After picking up all the items how can I count them to do another function? because after I collect items I want to fix something.

Comment: @saad Thanks. If this answer has solved your current problem, please put a green tick and ask the counting part in another question so I can answer there. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The code should be as follows:

```
public GameObject objectWithPlayer,PicUpText;
public RawImage objectRawImage;
private bool active;

void Start()
{
    objectWithPlayer.SetActive(false);
    objectRawImage.enabled = false;
    PicUpText.SetActive(false);
}

private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    if(other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        PicUpText.SetActive(true);
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            objectWithPlayer.SetActive(false);
            objectRawImage.enabled = true;
            
            //gameObject.SetActive(false);
            //cutterWithPlayer.SetActive(true);
            //cutter.enabled = true;
            PicUpText.SetActive(false);
          
        }
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    PicUpText.SetActive(false);       
}
```